# Run Sub in Workbook B on Workbook B from Workbook A

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks, workbook A and workbook B.  Workbook B grabs data using a SQL connection, performs some calculations (filtering) on the data, then populates a chart using a Public Sub called Calculate123.

I want to open workbook B from workbook A, run Calculate123 on workbook B, send the result to workbook A, then close workbook B without ever having seen workbook B open.

This code will open workbook B without it being visible and refresh the connection data.

How do I instruct workbook B to run Calculate123 on itself from workbook A?  I tried using Applications.Run variations - those all opened new windows.  I tried Call, that runs the Sub in worksheet A.

```
Public Sub openExcel()

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim sourceWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim sourceWS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim updater As Range

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    With xlApp
        .Visible = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        '.UserControl = False
        '.DisplayAlerts = False
        .AskToUpdateLinks = False
End With

strFile = "S:\Service\KPI Project\Daily Numbers - John Doe.xlsm"  'Put your file path.

Set sourceWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFile, , False, , , , , , , True)
sourceWB.Activate

Set sourceWS = xlApp.ActiveSheet

sourceWB.RefreshAll
'this line is where the call would be.  I tried the following combinations:

'Run.Application("'filepath'"!Calculate123)
'sourceWB.Call
'sourceWB.Run
'sourceWS.Call
'sourceWS.Run
'Run.Application("filepatch"!module8)
'xlApp.Run("'filepath'")
'xlApp.Run(Calculate123)

xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
xlApp.Quit

'possible garbage cleaning?  not sure
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set sourceWB = Nothing
Set sourceWS = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you *try* to see what `Application.Run` could possibly be used for?

Comment: "I tried using Applications.Run variations - those all opened new windows."  If you show your non-working code, we might be able to help you fix it.  (It might be as simple as removing the "s" from the end of "Applications"!)  But just showing a comment saying `'Run Sub code goes here?` doesn't help us find your error.

Comment: Or it might be that, instead of just removing one character from `Applications.Run`, it needs to have 2 characters added and 9 characters removed - but it is hard to be sure without seeing the code you tried.

Comment: I did try Application.Run.  As I said, it opened in a new window.  I also added my code here.  I'm not sure what's wrong with my post - both of these responses were addressed in the original body of my question, unless my code is not visible for some reason.

I tried all of the following:

Run.Application ("'filepath'"!Calculate123),
sourceWB.Call, sourceWB.Run, sourceWS.Call, sourceWS.Run, Run.Application("filepatch"!module8), xlApp.Run("'filepath'"),xlApp.Run(Calculate123)...  That's all I can remember, but I tried it about a dozen other ways.

Comment: Every different combination of Run.Application either ran the Sub on worksheet A, opened a new window or didn't compile/did nothing.

Comment: If you showed, in the question (instead of in a comment) some of the things you had tried, it would have made our life a lot easier in trying to assist you.  I have **attempted** to answer showing what was wrong with what I **think** you put in the comment - but reading code from comments is very difficult.  (Which is why we usually insist you add the code to the question itself.)  (And I would still suggest you edit your attempts into the question - otherwise the answer only helps you, and not anyone else with similar problems in the future.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you tried the following commands:

```
Run.Application("'filepath'"!Calculate123)
'Would fail because "Run" won't have an "Application" method, and because the parameter
' to "Run" should be a string

sourceWB.Call
'Would fail because "sourceWB" is an object in the existing application and
' Workbooks don't have a "Call" method

sourceWB.Run
'Would fail because "sourceWB" is an object in the existing application and
' Workbooks don't have a "Run" method

sourceWS.Call
'Would fail because "sourceWS" is an object in the existing application and
' Worksheets don't have a "Call" method

sourceWS.Run
'Would fail because "sourceWS" is an object in the existing application and
' Worksheets don't have a "Run" method

Run.Application("filepatch"!module8)
'Would fail because "Run" won't have an "Application" method, and because the parameter
' to "Run" should be a string specifying the name of the subroutine

xlApp.Run("'filepath'")
'Would fail because the parameter to "Run" should be the name of the subroutine

xlApp.Run(Calculate123)
'Would fail because the parameter to "Run" should be a string
```

---

Replace the line saying

```
'Run Sub code goes here?
```

with

```
xlApp.Run "Calculate123"
```

Comment: My goodness, thank you!  I knew it was possible, I'm just not great with syntax and knowing what scope I'm in, etc.  Works beautifully.